# Jenkins in-process script approval

Tags: java, security, jenkins, groovy

I would like to disable the "Approve" Option in the in-process script approval section of Manage Jenkins. I'm writing Job DLS that creates Jenkins jobs on the fly, but there is a lot of approvals I must complete to allow the script to execute. If there is a solution, one that can be turned on or off as a method call in a pipeline would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to disable the `In-process Script Approval` feature in Jenkins but you can "auto-approve" with the Permissive Script Security Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin)